# Codeigniter and google api integration fail

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api-php-client

I am trying to call google api from codeigniter. I have unzipped the google api php library in a directory named asset of the codeigniter root directory. I use the following code to create a user.

```
require_once 'assets/vendor/autoload.php';
$domain="xxxxxxx.com";

class Google_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function Create_User($dir,$Given_Name,$Family_Name,$User_Name,$Password)//create a user 
    {
        global $domain;
        $UserInstance = new Google_Service_Directory_User(); 
        $NameInstance = new Google_Service_Directory_UserName(); 

        $NameInstance -> setGivenName($Given_Name); 
        $NameInstance -> setFamilyName($Family_Name); 

        $UserInstance -> setName($NameInstance); 
        $UserInstance -> setHashFunction("MD5"); 
        $UserInstance -> setPrimaryEmail("$User_Name@$domain"); 
        $UserInstance -> setPassword(hash("md5", $Password)); 
        $Create_Error=1;
        try 
        { 
            $createUserResult = $dir -> users -> insert($UserInstance); 
            $Create_Error=0;
        } 
        catch (Google_IO_Exception $gioe) 
        { 
            $Create_Error=$gioe->getMessage(); 
        } 
        catch (Google_Service_Exception $gse) 
        { 
            $Create_Error=$gse->getMessage(); 
        } 
        return $Create_Error;
    }

    function Insert_User($First_Name,$Last_Name,$User_Name,$Password)
    {
        global $domain;
        $Error=0;

        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setAuthConfig('assets/auth/service_account.json');
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user');
        $email="admin@$domain";
        $client->setSubject($email);

        $dir = new Google_Service_Directory($client);
        $Error=self::Exist_user($dir,$User_Name);
        if(!$Error)
        {
            $Error=self::Create_User($dir,$First_Name,$Last_Name,$User_Name,$Password);
        }

        return $Error;
    }
}
```

When I use Insert_User routine to create a user, it fails after calling the function Create_User on the line

```
$createUserResult = $dir -> users -> insert($UserInstance);
```

with an error Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined method Google_Service_Directory_User::toSimpleObject()

Filename: Service/Resource.php

Line Number: 108

Backtrace:

How can I fix this?

Comment: The best way to include google API version 2 is by using composer. It is the easiest and official way. I explained the detailed procedure in my blog.You can refer the following link to know more if you want. http://shareurcodes.com/blog/login%20with%20google%20codeigniter

Comment: @GeordyJames: I installed using composer and re-tried. I still get the same message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for the failure. It is unlikely that anyone will come across this error, but will put the reason here should anyone be interested in this post. Turns out there is a class Google_Model that seems to conflict with the model name I have chosen (Google_model). Once I re-wrote the declaration as

```
class Google_API_Model extends CI_Model
```

the error goes away..